# Invalid attribute AuraDefinationBundle

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, aura-framework

I'm using VS code for Salesforce development. I've created a Aura Component and getting this error (**see screenshots**) every time. Every time if something wrong with variable name and If I correct it, previous error stays at the same line.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Aura component is more than just "cmp" file. Visual Studio might be attributing it to wrong file. Check the controller, helper, css and design file (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm). What's the actual error in SFDX CLI in Output tab? Or what happens if you manually save the file with CLI (force:source:push etc commands)

Comment: All other files are empty except this cmp file. and there is same error coming in the output tab when try to deploy it to org. There is nothing in this whole project again except this cmp file. I really don't know why and how this error is getting

Comment: They shouldn't be completely empty, suspicious. What if you go to this org, developer console and try to save the component in there. And then download the component to vs?

Comment: Did that, but again same. I created new aura components in org and download it in vs, but after saving, it gives same error again 

Comment: Can I delete cache or something in vs code, if yes how to do that?

Comment: There's `.sfdx\indexes\lwc\custom-components.json` but probably just for lwc. Run `sfdx update`, If you get same error with sfdx maybe try at https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues. If it's "just" in VSCode then hit plugin's project? https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode. Can you try against another sandbox?